# Is this integer optimization problem still NP?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, computational-complexity

I have the following integer optimization problem
\begin{align}\min&\quad\sum_ix_i\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad Ax \geq b\\
&\quad x \geq 0,\\
&\quad x \in \mathbb{Z}^n\end{align} where
$b$ is a general vector of integers,
$A$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix where all entries are integers, but it has a very specific format: it is symmetric, every entry in the main diagonal is equal to the opposite of the sum of its row/column except when $i=j$, and if $i \neq j$, $A_{ij}$ is either 0 or 1. I will try to write that more formally.

\begin{align}A_{ij} &\in \{0, 1\}\quad\text{if}\quad i \neq j\\A_{ii} &= -\sum_{j=0,j \neq i}^{n-1}A_{ij} = -\sum_{j=0,j \neq i}^{n-1}A_{ji}\end{align}

Example of $A$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & -3 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & -3 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
According to wikipedia, a general ILP is NP-hard. How do I:

1. Prove this specific format is still NP-hard (probably by some reduction) or find that this is a special case that can be solved in polynomial time?
2. Find if it's feasible without actually solving the optimization problem?

Comment: Welcome to OR Stack Exchange. The vector $b$ has no sign restrictions (can contain positive, negative and zero components)?

Comment: hello. Yes, no sign restrictions

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer to the feasibility question. Let $e\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector with all components equal to 1. $Ax\ge b \implies e'Ax \ge e'b.$ Since $e'A=0,$ if the problem is feasible you must have $e'b\le 0.$ So if the sum of the components of $b$ is positive, the problem is infeasible.

Comment: It's an interesting partial result. What do you think would be a natural next step to try?

Comment: Sorry, other than trying an IP solver or maybe a constraint solver, I don't see a natural way to proceed.

Comment: There are various metaheuristics you can try to use to find a feasible solution, but I don't think they are better than using an IP or CP solver in this case.